# Does hitting green on stroke 1 also count as fairway hit?

Tags: statistics, golf

When or if I hit the green on par 4 on my first stroke, does that count as fairway hit aswell or do I simply just remove that hole from my stat card (regarding fairwayhits)?

Comment: Well if you hit the green, I'd assume you would have hit a fairway to get there.  Or are you talking, if you hit the green on your first shot of a par 4?  At that point, I Believe, it's simply a green in regulation, and no fairway is counted, basically as if the fairway never existed.

Comment: @New-To-It Yes, I'm talking about hitting the green on the first shot on a pair 4. You have any source on that? I been googling and searching and I found a lot of different answers. For example, how do they handle it on the PGA tour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statistics are not always based on the rules of the game, so any answer you get really depends on the interpretation of the individual keeping the statistic or the system used to measure the statistic.

The PGA Tour counts hitting the green from your tee-shot as a Fairway hit. Reference the bottom of the table on the below link you will see:

> The percentage of time a shot comes to rest on the fairway or the green.

[Hit Fairway Statistics PGA Tour 2017](https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.213.html)

However, the [Chart Golf Stats](http://www.chartmygolf.com/General/HelpDir/GolfingTerms.aspx) website claims it counts as a 'no-score':

> Note: on par 3 holes, where you are meant to hit the green with your tee shot, you do not record fairways hit, instead recording no-score.

Similarly, [My Scorecard](http://www.myscorecard.com/cgi-bin/knowledgecenter.pl?mode=article&category=golfer&file=greensfairways&article=Statistics:-Greens-) also states that hitting the green from the tee does not count as a fairway hit...

> This statistic refers to the number of times during the round your drive landed in the fairway (the fairway, not the light rough). It is similar to the greens in regulation, except that the maximum number per round is less than 18. This is due to the fact that you are supposed to drive the green on a par 3, and as a result we don't count those holes for the fairways statistic.

EDIT:
My interpretation of the statistic sites is that, on a Par 4, hitting the green WILL count, while on a Par 3 it won't count. However, the statistic is not relevant on a Par 3 as you are not intended to hit the fairway at all, therefore hitting the fairway on a Par 3 is actually a bad thing and should be considered a negative statistic.

In short, hitting the green on a Par 4 should count as a fairway hit and a green in regulation.

My advice is to follow the local rules. If your golf club has a statistic system they follow then ask them, if they don't then choose a system and follow their rules.

Comment: I was primarly intrested in the PGA Tour way of handling the statistic and since you anser it perfectly will I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: Neither Chart Golf Stats nor My Scorecard mentions driving the green on a par 4, which is what this question is about.

Comment: This is true. My interpretation of the statistic sites is that, on a Par 4, hitting the green WILL count while on a Par 3 it wont but the statistic is not relevant on a Par 3 as you are not intended to hit the fairway at all, therefore hitting the fairway on a Par 3 is actually a bad thing and should be considered a negative statistic.
I will update my answer to include this assumption.